# Strange path to script: chrome://some_path/script.js

Tags: browser, script

Sometimes a script causes your browser to stop responding, so the browser allows you to stop the script.

In my case it is: `chrome://some_path/script.js.`

Now my question is: what is the meaning of `chrome://`? I am using firefox/ie, not chrome.

Anyone has any references to some literature about this?

Comment: Also see [Firefox add-on RestClient says Chrome://restclient/content/ how?](http://superuser.com/questions/485845/firefox-add-on-restclient-says-chrome-restclient-content-how)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes back a bit, but Mozilla (which is the non-profit org behind Firefox) programmers sometimes refer to XUL (XML User Interface Language) applications running locally as chrome.

Wikipedia covers it here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_Mozilla

This predates the launch of Google Chrome by quite some time, but I can see why you might confuse the two.